# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I was learning Classification-based collaboration system and while running the code I faced the error **AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'**. Here is the code I write until now.
`X=bank_full.ix[:,(18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36)].values`

Comment: The 'logistic regression' and 'numpy' tags are irrelevant to this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

> Warning: Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor
> of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers.

Just use `.iloc` instead (for positional indexing) or `.loc` (if using the values of the index).

To read more about loc/ilic/iax/iat, please visit [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/pandas-loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat). To quote the top answer there:

> loc: only work on index iloc: work on position ix: You can get data
> from dataframe without it being in the index at: get scalar values.
> It's a very fast loc iat: Get scalar values. It's a very fast iloc
>
> http://pyciencia.blogspot.com/2015/05/obtener-y-filtrar-datos-de-un-dataframe.html
>
> Note: As of pandas 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated in favour of
> the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers.

Answer (score 1):

use the loc or iloc instead of ix